# Creating a SOAP request for Allegro WebAPI

Tags: xml, soap, allegro-pl

Could anybody help me with creating XML request for Allegro WebAPI?

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<SOAP-ENV:Envelope ' + 
    'xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' + 
    'xmlns:main="https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php" ' +
    'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
    '<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
        '<main:DoGetItemsInfoRequest>' +
            '<main:sessionHandle>xxxxxxxxx</main:sessionHandle>' +

   'HERE GOES <itemsIdArray> with auction ids, and I have no idea how to create it'

            '<main:getDesc>1</main:getDesc>' +
        '</main:DoGetItemsInfoRequest>' +
    '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
'</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
```

Unfortunately Allegro does not show any samples for WebAPI! 
I am using REST API in my app but this request has to be made with old WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, already solved and works as below:

```html
<itemsIdArray>
  <item>123456789</item>
  <item>123456789</item>
</itemsIdArray>
```